# Ubuntu 16.04, Nvidia driver issues

Tags: ubuntu

Ok first off I tried installing the nvidia-current-updates but upon reboot both Unity and Cinnamon crashed.  Removed them then tried the official 361-42 drivers.  I can login to a desktop but there's no window panes nor any panels.

Im running an Asus ROG G751 with a GTX 965M

Comment: Use LinuxMint instead of Ubuntu, it has much better support for Asus laptops, including nvidia graphics drivers and audio support.

Answer (score 0):

I am also running an asus ROG G751 with GTX 965M, and I was also having these problems. I fixed it by disabling Secure Boot.

- Restart and F2 to enter Bios
- Go to Security tab and select the Secure Boot option menu
- Disable Secure Boot, F10 to save and exit

Comment: Nice I will give that a shot.